# Creating an installation file with the WIX tool set along with SQL data recording

Tags: sql-server, installation, wix

I'm creating a supplementary toolset for the Advance Steel (AS) software, consisting of DLL files and images. To install this toolset, it requires copying these files into two installation directories of the AS software (chosen by the user from a window), recording data into the AS database using SQL, and additionally recording data into an XML file. I have created a project with the following code, but when running the installation, it reports an error:

> Failed to connect to SQL database (-2147467259 ASTORRULES)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
    xmlns:sql="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/SqlExtension">
    <?define MyWpfApplication_TargetDir=$(var.MyWpfApplication.TargetDir)?>
    <?define Win64 = "yes" ?>
    <?define SqlInstanceName = "YourInstanceNameHere" ?>
    <?define WixExtension ="WixSqlExtension" ?>
  <Product Id="17a4f85a-1219-4143-a0d6-e9ebc6084064" Name="My Wpf Application" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Mesta-Automation.com" UpgradeCode="3936e1bc-c06c-45ae-b1db-430cf31dd48b">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    
    <Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)Icon.ico" />
    <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon.ico" />

    <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="Images\installer_top-banner.bmp" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="Images\installer_background.bmp" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="$(var.ProjectDir)\license.rtf" />

    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />


    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="My Wpf Application" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut" />
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" />

        <!--
         <ComponentGroupRef Id="Files_files" /> -->
    </Feature>

      <Binary Id="CreateUpsizingDatabase" SourceFile="FILECAIDAT\dbo.RULE_HRLDefinition.sql" />
      <util:User Id="SQLUser" Name="ADMINISTRATOR\CANHQUY" />
      <sql:SqlDatabase Id="SqlDatabase" Database="ASTORRULES" Server="(LocalDB)\AdvanceSteel2022" User="SQLUser" />

  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyWpfApplication">
          <Directory Id="Files" Name="Files" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="MyWpfApplication" />
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="9bd13330-6540-406f-a3a8-d7f7c69ae7f9">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" Name="MyWpfApplication" Description="MyWpfApplication" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]MyWpfApplication.exe" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveApplicationProgramsFolder" Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\MyWpfApplication" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" Guid="cde1e030-eb64-49a5-b7b8-400b379c2d1a">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut" Name="MyWpfApplication" Description="MyWpfApplication" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]MyWpfApplication.exe" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveDesktopFolder" Directory="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\MyWpfApplication" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
 
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
> TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
      <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
> TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
      <!-- </Component> -->
      <Component Id="file_ASNetJoints.dll" Guid="0f9a1acd-803f-4ecb-a283-7537a05a5eb1">
        <File Id="file_ASNetJoints.dll" Name="ASNetJoints.dll" Source="FILECAIDAT\ASNetJoints.dll" />
      </Component>
        <Component Id="SqlComponent" Guid="15CCE46E-8EA5-42CA-80C5-AC3DB30A9716">
            <sql:SqlScript Id="CreateDatabases" SqlDb="SqlDatabase" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="CreateUpsizingDatabase" />
            <CreateFolder/>
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
    
  </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <!-- Định nghĩa Binary cho file SQL -->
        <Binary Id="SqlScriptBinary" SourceFile="FILECAIDAT\dbo.RULE_HRLDefinition.sql" />

        <CustomAction Id="ChangeSqlScript"
BinaryKey="Installer.CA"
DllEntry="ChangeSqlScript"
Execute="immediate"
Return="check"
Impersonate='yes'/>
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="ChangeSqlScript" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed AND VersionNT</Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Fragment>

</Wix>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXC4e.png)

Please help me identify the error in the above code.

Comment: Welcome!  The title of your question mentions WIX.  What documentation have you reviewed as it pertains to your question?

Comment: <...User="SQLUser" /> This looks suspicious, a window auth doesn't specify username, maybe it works without it. Alternatively, you need to see which attributes you need to set in the above xml to use windows auth (usually called TrustedConnection)